# Suspicion of a java memory leak in the decompression of MHA volumes in Matlab

Tags: java, matlab, image-processing, out-of-memory, inflate

I have many volumes stored as `.mha` files which I usually open in Matlab by using a function called `mha_read_volume`, which you can find on [Matlab Central](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3ak8mN8TY8ryoJ%3awww.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/29344-read-medical-data-3d/content/mha/mha_read_volume.m). My problem is this function *randomly* throws an out-of-memory error message related to the decompressing of these images with some java library.

The culprit seems to lie here:

```
function M = zlib_decompress(Z,DataType)
import com.mathworks.mlwidgets.io.InterruptibleStreamCopier
a=java.io.ByteArrayInputStream(Z);
b=java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream(a);
isc = InterruptibleStreamCopier.getInterruptibleStreamCopier;
c = java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
isc.copyStream(b,c);
M=typecast(c.toByteArray,DataType);
```

I suspect a memory leak, but I have no idea what to do with this code to fix the problem.

Here is the error message:

```
??? Java exception occurred:
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray(Unknown Source)

Error in ==> mha_read_volume>zlib_decompress at 87
M=typecast(c.toByteArray,DataType);

Error in ==> mha_read_volume at 74
        V = zlib_decompress(Z,DataType);
```

Comment: Do you just not have enough memory on through platform you're using?

Comment: The problem is really random: sometimes, I launch Matlab and it won't open any file, sometimes it can open 50 files. Every time I open a volume, I assign it to the same variable, so the memory needed stays roughly the same, and should be way below my system specifications.

Comment: Hmm... I won't be much help; good luck!

Comment: I am unlucky: 1) the Matlab website is under maintenance, so I have to link to the Google Cache instead, and 2) I cannot reproduce the problem, which is annoying since it usually happens really often.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the files you read are large (their uncompressed version) this does not need to be a memory leak.
You can adjust the java heap space matlab uses in the matlab preferences.
Usually it is set to a rather small value of 128 MB - increase it and see if the problem persists.

To check whether it is a memory leak, simply try something along:

```
for i=1:1000 % adjust loop-number to your needs
m = zlib_decompress(...)
end
```

If there is a leak, this should error out once your heap space is full again.
If not - your memory footprint should stay within certain limits.

Comment: Thanks. The thing is I manage to open the files if I close Matlab and try again, and repeat the process until it works, so it is really strange.

Answer (score 2):

It is important to close streams when job is over to free memory. Use [try/catch to ensure resources are freed](https://ch.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/300062-finally-clause-in-try-catch?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com) even in case of exceptions.

So you should invoke `c.close b.close a.close` to be able to process large number of files in loop.

Remark (not related to your situation): Java 8 is known to leak native memory  if `java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream` streams are not closed. The reason is the replacement of pure-Java implementation by Hotspot calls to `zlib`.

Answer (score -1):

I might be late to answer this but this memory problem can be solved by adding the file `java.opts` in the current directory of Matlab workspace where you can specifiy the used memory by Matlab:

http://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/92813-how-do-i-increase-the-heap-space-for-the-java-vm-in-matlab-6-0-r12-and-later-versions

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It is never too late. However, I don't get the answer. Is it a text file with ".opts java cmd" written inside it?